# C program new segment declaration

Tags: c, header, portable-executable, segment, dumpbin

i've this simple code test code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* Declare new sections to store encrypted code and shellcode data */
#pragma section(".code", execute, read, write)
#pragma comment(linker,"/SECTION:.code,ERW")

// From here executable code will go in .code section
#pragma code_seg(".code")


int test()
{
    printf("prova");
    return 0;
}

// .stub SECTION
#pragma section(".stub", execute, read, write)
#pragma code_seg(".stub")

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    test(); /* Call function which executes shellcode now that it is decrypted */
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone tell me why if i dump this file i only got this default section:

- .data
- .rdata
- .reloc
- .rsrc
- .stub
- .text

The .code segment it's not generated. I think I used to do like this in some previuos project, am i doing something wrong?

-- Further tests --

- Dumping the `.obj` file the `.code` section is shown.
- `.stub` gets showed dumping `.exe` or `.obj`
- removing `#pragma comment(linker,"/SECTION:.code,ERW")` did not work
- adding `#pragma comment(linker,"/SECTION:.stub,ERW")` didn't change dumpbin result on `.exe`, `.stub` still showing
- change the name from `.code` to `.somethingelse` didn't work either, same result

Comment: Are you dumping the executable file, or the object file?

Comment: i'm dumping the .exe

Comment: Anyway the .stub gets created @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: If you dump the object file, is the section in it? Perhaps the default linker script have a case for a sections with the name `.code`? Or perhaps it have check for executable sections (which you set using the `/SECTION` option using a pragma, but only for `.code`)?

Comment: Yes @Someprogrammerdude , there is the section in the obj, i've just tried using another name but still the same result (shown in the obj and not show in the exe).
N.B. the stub gets created everytime

Comment: Then a last experiment: What happens if you do `#pragma comment(linker,"/SECTION:.stub,ERW")`? Do the `.stub` sections still exist in the executable?

Comment: nothing changed @Someprogrammerdude , i even tried to remove `#pragma comment(linker,"/SECTION:.code,ERW")`. The stub is there and the code is not. I've even checked the path multiple time coping the one in the compilation output and tried to clean rebuild the project but nothing changed

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not able to help you further. Please edit your question to include the results of these experiments, and hopefully someone more knowledgeable would be able to help you.

Comment: add `/MAP` to linker option, this will be most informative. however `#pragma code_seg(".code")` is worked as excepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following directives i was able to confine all the code/variable/costant into the `.code` segment which was visible using the dumbin command.

```
#pragma section(".code", execute, read)
#pragma section(".codedata", read, write)
#pragma comment(linker,"/SECTION:.code,ERW")
#pragma comment(linker,"/SECTION:.codedata,ERW")
#pragma comment(linker, "/MERGE:.codedata=.code")

#pragma code_seg(".code")
#pragma data_seg(".codedata")
#pragma const_seg(".codedata")
```